# swap 2 values in excel selection

Tags: excel, vba

In a variable selection of cells in single column, I'm needing to swap "Buy" with "Sell", and vice-versa.

I tried something like this...but when first Selection.Replace changes "Sell" to "Buy", then 2nd one just changes "Buy" back to "Sell" -

[Data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iMIA.png)

I havent found that I can nest a Selection.Replace..would need to loop down thru each cell somehow?

....

```
  Range("B4").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("C4").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial
     
    Selection.Replace What:="Bought", Replacement:="Sold", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="Sold", Replacement:="Bought", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
```

Comment: If you could add an excel screenshot, perhaps it could help you explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: sure..in data sample above, if BOUGHT, change to SOLD - if SOLD change to BOUGHT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you can replace three times instead of just two times.

The solution shows how to do it, while avoiding the use of **Copy**, **Paste** and **Select**, to make sure we don't interfere with the user selection and the clipboard.

```vb
Sub Doit()
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim Rng2 As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Lst As Variant
    
    ' Get the range in column B from row 4 and down.
    Set Rng1 = Range("B4")
    Set Rng2 = Rng1.End(xlDown)
    Set Rng = Range(Rng1, Rng2)

    ' Copy the range to column C
    Lst = Rng
    Range("C4").Resize(UBound(Lst, 1), UBound(Lst, 2)) = Lst

    ' Replace Bought with Sold and Sold with Bought
    Rng.Replace What:="Bought", Replacement:="#B#o#u#g#h#t", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Rng.Replace What:="Sold", Replacement:="Bought", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Rng.Replace What:="#B#o#u#g#h#t", Replacement:="Sold", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
End Sub
```

The solution assumes that your data does not contain the string "#B#o#u#g#h#t". You can use whatever string you want instead of "#B#o#u#g#h#t", as long as the string does not appear in your data.

As with your example, the solution does not test, if there is any valid data in Column B from row 4 and down.

Comment: awesome, thanks Gowlser!

Comment: Please be kind and accept the answer if it solves your problem :D